# Open Office - how to control spaces between words

Tags: openoffice.org

I am making a job in `Open Office Writer`. When justifying I get paragraphs like this one:

[image: problem_image]

Where " habitan en los Campos Elíseos" looks really bad.

I have tried with `condense` text option in `characters` but it doesn't change the text.
Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu are you running?  By the way, I'll notice a response quicker if @L.D.James is included in your response.

Comment: @L.D.James a debian version, but i suppose the problem is the same for both..

Comment: I'm fairly fluent with the Ubuntu applications and how their behavior in the Ubuntu environment.  I understand that Ubuntu is a derivative of Debian.  But I'm not the most fluent with Debian itself.  I test my recommendations on all the supported versions of Ubuntu before posting.  I don't know the Debian version control and what is current and what is not.  If you are using an outdated OS version, that could contribute to issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you have used <kbd>Shift</kbd> +  <kbd>Enter</kbd> at the end of line to start the new paragraph.
You should start it with just a  <kbd>Enter</kbd> or if you don't want to use  <kbd>Enter</kbd>  just add a  <kbd>Tab</kbd>  at the end of line.

Comment: I can't understand your answer, I only wrote in open office without using anything..

Comment: Oh, I think I understood now. I will try your solution

Comment: You used the block text format and forced a new line but without ending the paragraph as @Mirza said. So Open Office tries to fill the line